# Honda City vTec Slow Start

Tags: honda, clutch, manual-transmission, rpm, vtec

I have a Honda City 2005 vTec Manual Transmission Car, which will be due for servicing in another 1000KM.

I am not well used to driving manual car and I face a lot of traffic everyday going and coming back from work but what I noticed recently was that anytime I press the gas, the rpm comes up to 2k and the speedometer reading like 20KMPH without gaining much distance as before.

What do you think might be wrong? Please help!

Comment: I just changed the fuel filter of recent.

Comment: Are you saying your engine revs up (gains rpms) while the vehicle doesn't go much faster if any?

Comment: @Paulster2 You are definitely correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem would appear to be that your clutch is slipping (going out) and will need replacement soon. After the clutch gets worn enough, it can no longer hold the torque/power which the engine can produce and starts to slip.

Comment: I asked my mechanic and he asked me to come and install a new clutch chain tomorrow... That something is loosed inside there and it needs to be tightened ...

Comment: Maybe there is a translation issue here, but to my knowledge there is no such thing as a *clutch **chain*** ... maybe he said a clutch cable? Even so, your 2005 Honda should be using a hydraulic clutch system where there isn't an adjustment for it. If it was going out you'd find the transmission hard to go into gear, not that the clutch was slipping. I'll still hold fast to my suggestion you'll need a new clutch.

Comment: Yes... I meant clutch cable. Thanks for your suggestion.